# Flutter Issue | Keystore file not set for signing config release

Tags: flutter

Running the command `flutter build appbundle --release` or `flutter build apk --release`
I have this issue

> Keystore file not set for signing config release

I'd follow the steps of the flutter.dev/docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle but still the same.

I create the key.propeties file and replace the content in the build.grade file.

[Build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp4dh.png)

[Key.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGNPp.png)

Also replace de build types with:

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

But still getting the same issue:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

> Keystore file not set for signing config release

Somebody already solve this issue?

Comment: Neither `key.propeties` nor `build.grade` look the correct file name.

Answer (score 42):

The instructions [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#configure-signing-in-gradle) did not work for me out of the box. I had to change the `key.properties` file path to:

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('app/key.properties')
```

You can test your configuration is being read properly or not by printing the values to the console. For example, in your gradle file you can have:

```
println keystorePropertiesFile
```

to make sure that object is populated with the values you expect

Comment: This is weird since it wasn't necessary to do so in my case at all.

Comment: Maybe your path was set correctly. I'm not sure how Flutter generates these files and under which conditions the properties file path could be off

Comment: Hell yeah. After 12 hours of searching, this one worked fine. Thank you

Comment: This solved the problem and don't even know why

Comment: This is happening just because you put the key.properties file in the "app" folder under android, instead of directly in "android".

Comment: Also note, it's suggested to not check the key.properties file into version control. I lost my file after performing a removal of the project and adding it back again. make sure you have a back up of it.  https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#under-the-defaultconfig-block

Comment: In my case, my key.properties file was missing inside my /android/ folder

Answer (score 30):

My issue was that I've put the `key.properties` file in the folder `/android/app` and it was meant to be in `/android/`

Comment: ooops, the same issue for me

Comment: Thanks, more information about [key.properties file can be found here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app)

Answer (score 13):

This one is for windows users.
Inside key.properties i was using:

```
storeFile= C:\users\username\key.jks
```

instead we need to use:

```
storeFile= C:/users/username/key.jks
```

This solved my issue!

Comment: Thanks, none of the above comments worked, but this one did! 
+1 for this.

Comment: Roses are red violets are blue you missed three '/' in line 31.

Answer (score 9):

The same problem I faced and after doing lots of R&D ....
I have done these:
First Executed this command:`keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\Ziya\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key`

Then in key.properties: Changed the ***storeFile*** to this value:   `C:\\Users\\Ziya\\key.jks`

Then Result I got:

```
flutter build appbundle
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done
    5.3s
√ Built build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab        
(17.7MB).
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to Create a file that have key prperties in path like that

```
[project]/android/key.properties
```

And that's File data

```
storePassword=password
keyPassword=password
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=C:/user/project/upload-keystore.jks
```

Comment: This worked for me on a MacBook with an M1 chip.. thank you>

Answer (score 6):

If you want to build APK files for testing purposes make sure that you use a debug signing configuration in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

My Problem was that I stored the key.properties file in app folder instead of android folder.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing `"` from the path mentioned for keystore file

that seems to be the problem.

contents of `key.properties` files should be like this

```
storePassword=XXXXXX
keyPassword=XXXXXXXX
keyAlias=key
storeFile=D:/XXXX/XXXXX/key.jks
```

Answer (score 4):

My mistake was to insert values instead of variables.
Do not change signingConfigs {...} block

Mistake:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['key']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['12345678qwerty']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['/Users/Me/key.jks'] ? file(keystoreProperties['/Users/Me/key.jks']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['12345678qwerty']
    }
}
```

Right code:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a key.properties file inside the android folder. If you created a key.properties file inside app folder then maybe this error occurs.
I also have faced this issue.

Answer (score 4):

originally app->build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

just replace the release to debug in
signingConfigs.release to signingConfigs.debug.
Your problem will be solved

Answer (score 3):

**In my case this was because I have not added key.properties file and not even created my keystore**

*So what i have done. Creates a new keystore file and added new key.properties file in Folder[ android/ ]*

First step is to create new keystore file with this command 
For mac/linux

```
  keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

and for windows

```
  keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\Users\USER_NAME\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload
```

Second Step :

Create a new key.properties file and add to
`android/key.properties`

> Make sure to provide password and storeFile like:

```
storePassword=<password from previous step>
keyPassword=<password from previous step>
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=<location of the key store file, such as /Users/<user name>/upload-keystore.jks>
```

Reference
[Official flutter release build doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore)

Comment: thanks, key.properties works for me finally.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix it by the following operation using android studio.

**Before fix**

Create key.propeties from
File> New> File

[image before fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAgy3.png)

**After fix**
Create key.propeties from
File> New> Resource Bundle

[image after fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z440Q.png)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@Tomas Baran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7200875/tomas-baran)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61978535/13109342) worked for me

For windows user :

1. Place the `key.jks` file in `/<project-directory>/android/app/Users/user_name/`
2. Open `key.properties` file which must be (created and edited accordingly if not already) in the `<project-directory>/android` folder.
3. Now edit the value of the `storeFile` in `key.properties` file to `/User/user_name/key.jks`.

For Linux users :

1. Do same as instructed above from steps 1 to 2.
2. Edit the value of the `storeFile` in `key.properties` file to `User/user_name/key.jks`

> NOTE: (preceeding `/` is removed).

That's it it should work for you now !

Answer (score 1):

This states the path you stored the key.properties file on your application, keeping it inside the android folder is good since it concerns only the android signing

```
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('app/key.properties')


Change this

storePassword=<XXXXX>
keyPassword=<XXXXXX>
keyAlias=key
storeFile=<C:/Users/saint/Desktop/key.jks>

to 

storePassword=XXXXXX
keyPassword=XXXXXXXX
keyAlias=key
storeFile=D:/XXXX/XXXXX/key.jks
```

Answer (score 1):

As meant by the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android), I needed to run `flutter clean`

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for error `Flutter Issue | Keystore file not set for signing config release`

It's a simple mistake. Check your key information file name.

I named it with can extra `s` e.g. `keys.properties` instead of `key.properties`

Answer (score 1):

It was two parts that solved this for me:
I had to move the key.properties file from *android/app* to *android*.
I also had to change the slash in key.properties from
`storeFile=c:\Users\MYNAME\key.jks` to
`storeFile=c:/Users/MYNAME/key.jks`.
That worked to solve the issues for me.

Comment: The main key for me too was to move the key.jks file to android folder from android/app

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I originally set the path to my key.jks in the key.properties like this:

```
storeFile=~/key.jks
```

and it couldn't read it so all I had to do was change it to:

```
storeFile=Users/tomas/key.jks
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to how I was storing the CI variables in Gitlab. Turns out if CI Variables are protected, they will not be printed via `echo` to a file (which is what I was using). Unprotecting the variable fixed my issue (in a private repo) but that should not be done for public projects.

Answer (score 0):

have you change for example the application ID ?
and check if the key.prporties file is there

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial here has some issue https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

In the key.properties remove any <> around the password
also in the path of the key , remove the quotations it will work

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a error because you don't have a `buildTypes{ release{ signingConfig signingConfigs.release}` at your build.gradle... I had the same issue and this solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this error and I solved it by adding the drive name for `storeFile`, something like:

```
C:/xxx/xxx/key.jks
```

Of course, in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem using like this

```
storePassword=xxx
keyPassword=xxx
keyAlias=key
storeFile=F:\\xxx\\key.jks

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same problem. I solve my problem following this step:

Step 1: Put the `upload-keystore.jks` file in the project folder android/app

[image]

Step 2: Set path `storeFile= ../app/upload-keystore.jks` in `key.properties` file

Step 3: flutter clean
Step 4: flutter pub get
Step 5: `flutter build apk` or `flutter build appbundle`

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was there was a space   after the storeFile path like: `storeFile=key.jks` .

I just removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

key.properties file should add to your project for more info visit
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on this issue about near 1 hour and very stress. I followed exactly document but it doesn't work. Finally I sovled this by

- Put key.properties in android/app
- just insert relative path with your file name like this `storeFile=your-key-file-name.jks`

And ... boom, it works! Moreover, be sure:

- In build.gradle `def keystorePropertiesFile = file('key.properties')`
- Remove any redundant space in key.properties
- Confirm and fill right keyAlias (`upload` is default)
- Config sigining `buildTypes {}`

  ```
  release {
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }
  ```

Comment: It worked to me. I used default key:  "upload". Also , just set the storeFile=upload_keystore.jks, that I placed into <project_home>/android/app/upload_keystore.jks.

Answer (score 0):

I just change the store file path and add the drive name in KeyProperties.
like this:

storeFile=C:/Users/shb.g-keystore.jks

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue with my Flutter app and here's how I solved it on my Mac.

1. First, ensure that your `key.properties` file is located inside the android directory, so the path should be `android/key.properties`.
2. Your key.properties file should have the following structure:

   ```
   storePassword=Yourpasswordgoeshere 
   keyPassword=Yourpasswordgoeshere
   keyAlias=key
   storeFile=/Users/yourUsername/Apps/yourappname/android/app/upload-keystore.jks
   ```
3. If you're unsure what your keyAlias key is, open your terminal and run this command `keytool -list -v -keystore /path/to/your/keystore` , replacing /path/to/your/keystore with the actual keystore path obtained when you run the `keytool -genkey` command. To find your keyAlias, search for
   `-alias`.

Alternatively, if you used Android Studio to generate your keystore, go to Build>Generate Signed Bundle/APK, select APK and the key store path, password and alias can be found there.

4. Open your build.gradle file located at `android>app>build.gradle`. Check that you've added the following code above the `android` block and below
   `apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle":`

   ```
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }
    android {..............// IGNORE THIS LINE
   ```
5. Within the defaultConfig block, check that you have also added the following code:

   ```
   signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
    buildTypes {
       release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
   ```

The minifyEnabled and proguardFiles keys are used for code shrinking and obfuscation.

6. Run `flutter clean && flutter pub get`
7. Run `flutter build appbundle`. If the build process completes successfully,  you will see  `✓ Built build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab`. This path indicates where the app bundle is stored within your Flutter project.

Answer (score 0):

replace the signingConfigs in android/app/build. Gradle with this

```
signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?