# build flutter with different flavors

Tags: android, flutter, android-build-flavors

Im trying to build my app in different environments, so i followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@vo9312/flutter-series-part-1-flutter-flavors-setup-bb6aba1586ac) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgGUtTUatDQ), when i run flutter works properly, everything works nicely, but when i try to build i got this error:

[image: erro1]

so i forgot to add some flavors, then i added in my build.gradle (android/app/build.gradle) to this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "secret-domain"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "app"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "app"
            applicationIdSuffix ".prod"
        }
        hml {
            dimension "app"
            applicationIdSuffix ".hml"
        }
    }
}
```

and got this error again:
[image: error2]

Comment: also, before a add this flavor and followed those tutorial, the build works perfectly

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787510/flutter-issue-keystore-file-not-set-for-signing-config-release

Answer (score 0):

in complement to [R.Shpd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6202449/r-shpd), my problem was that another developer before me had configured the build, put the key.properties in gitignore so the buildgradle never found the file