# Keystore file not set for signing config release flutter (when trying release mode)

Tags: android, flutter, apk, android-app-bundle

Hey there I need your help. I know there are many threads with this error, but I tried every single solution and nothing is working.

I did everything like it's mention in the documentation to get my app bundle, but I always get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release
```

I made the key.properties like this and saved it in the android folder (C:\Users\Martin\Documents\tutorial\android):

```
storePassword=XXXXXX
keyPassword=XXXXXX
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/Users/Martin/key.jks
```

I created my own keystore file which is located in /Users/Martin/

[image: keystorefile]

```
And finally I changed my build.gradle as mentioned in the documentation.

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('app/key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }




android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.myID"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }


   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'

}
```

I don't know if this is helpful, but if I try the debug mode

```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
   }
```

it works just fine and everything works.

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab (20.0MB).
```

What could cause this error in release mode but works in debug mode? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787510/flutter-issue-keystore-file-not-set-for-signing-config-release). You should correct a path to the Gradle properties (from `local.properties` to `app/local.properties`).

Comment: This leads to following error: * Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Martin\Documents\tutorial\maulwurf\android\app\build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.

Comment: Add variable `flutter.sdk` to `local.properties` file with valid path to Flutter SDK.

Comment: I am a beginner, could you guide me how to do this?

Comment: Just add `flutter.sdk=path_to_sdk` (where `path_to_sdk` is a valid path to your Flutter SDK (like `/Users/user/flutter/bin`)) to `local.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

SIMILAR PROBLEM ON ANDROID STUDIO WITH JAVA

I've encountered with the similar issue and I'm writing how I resolved it.
I wasn't even able to run the app, though the gradle was building the app well. I was getting this "Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available". And I tried these steps.

It is not a guaranteed solution but it at least worked for me.

- Keep the Android Studio running.
- Open C:\Android.android and Cut-Paste the "debug.keystore" file somwhere else. I'd prefer outside the C drive.
- Now go to C:\users{User Name}.android and delete or Cut-Paste the "debug.keystore" file.
- Now run your project in Android Studio.
- If the app got built, BINGO !!