# Keystore file not set for signing config release

Tags: flutter

Keystore file not set for signing config release
done so much R&D Nothing Works

[image: SS]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787510/flutter-issue-keystore-file-not-set-for-signing-config-release and cross check if you have done the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

did you added required codes in app/build.gradle ?

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {...
```

and this one:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
}
```