# failed to build flutter apk because of this error SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile"

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I have a flutter project and I wanted to get an apk for the app I tried `flutter build apk` command and I got this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".
```

I've tried this command `flutter build apk --release` but I also got the same error.

I also searched and tried different solutions but nothing fixed the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Issue | Keystore file not set for signing config release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787510/flutter-issue-keystore-file-not-set-for-signing-config-release)

Answer (score 1):

**General-ish solution that could work for you:**

Try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`.

If that doesn't work, you can try upgrading your Flutter SDK like so: `flutter upgrade`.

You can also run `flutter doctor` to see a list of possible issues with your code.

After running the set of commands, then try building the `.apk`.

Comment: I tried all these command and got the same error :"

Answer (score 0):

This might happen because you have signed your app, but the release build is not able to access the signing keys. If you followed any tutorial or the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) to sign the app, you've probably created a file called `key.properties`, which contains the `storePassword`, `keyPassword`, `keyAlias`, and `storeFile` fields used for the app signing process. So make sure that this file exists and has the correct data; also, pay attention to the `storeFile` as it is supposed to point out to a `jks` file, which serves as repositories of certificates and private keys.
The content of the `key.properties` is usually used in your app level build.gradle to read the needed fields for signing as below:

```
signingConfigs {
  release {
    v1SigningEnabled false
    v2SigningEnabled true
    enableV3Signing = true
    keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
    keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
    storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
    storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
  }
}
```